# Magento top navigation in CMS page

Tags: magento

I need to display magento top navigation in a CMS page. How is it possbile to call the nested layout xml in cms format like `{{block type="page/html_topmenu" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"}}`

Layout xml for top navigation

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do small modification in the topmenu.phtml file of your current theme. Here is the complete description for your solution. 
You can reorder the category menu and cms page menu with the [solution](http://subodhdhukuchhu.com.np/customizing-the-magento-top-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to system -> Permisisons -> Block and make sure the block "page/html_topmenu" is allowed.